# Using RETURNING clause to specify the data type of the return value of JSON_VALUE function call in Oracle using JPA Specification

Tags: oracle, jpa

I'm trying to use the RETURNING clause to specify the data type of the return value of the `JSON_VALUE` function call in Oracle using JPA Specification.

Here's how I am creating the JPA specification:

```java
(root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> cb.function(
      "JSON_VALUE", String.class,
      inlineExpression(cb, "data"),
      inlineExpression(cb, "'$.status' RETURNING VARCHAR(15) NULL ON ERROR"));
```

The `inlineLiteral` function returns `LiteralExpression<String>` that renders the provided string as it is.

The corresponding part of the generated HQL query becomes like this:

```sql
function('JSON_VALUE', data, '$.status' RETURNING VARCHAR2(15) NULL ON ERROR)
```

However, this fails at the `AbstractSharedSessionContract::createQuery` method and, in particular, at the `AbstractSharedSessionContract::getQueryPlan` with the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
   expecting CLOSE, found 'RETURNING' near line 1, column {x} 
     [select generatedAlias0 
      from MyEntity as generatedAlias0 
      where ( function('JSON_VALUE', data, '$.status' RETURNING VARCHAR2(15) NULL ON ERROR) = :param0
     ]
```

How can I use the RETURNING clause with the `JSON_VALUE` function in Oracle through JPA Specification without causing this `QuerySyntaxException`? Are there any alternatives or workarounds to achieve the desired functionality?